# Make report public in Odoo

Tags: report, odoo, public

I successfully created a simple report.

```
<report
    id="my_report"
    model="cars.car"
    string="Car"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="cars.my_report"
    file="views.xml"
    attachment_use="True"
    attachment="('CAR'+(object.name or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
/>
```

The problem is that I can only access it if I'm logged in to Odoo backend. How do I make a report public? I tried with parameter groups="base.group_no_one", but no success. Same for 'base.group_public'.

I found a guy with the exact same question here: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/allow-website-guests-to-download-certain-reports-105042

...but sadly Odoo forum has been dead for some time now. Nobody answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to this, so I've hacked it?

In the 'report' module, under controllers there is main.py file. I changed the auth parameter on line 24 to:

```
auth="public"
```

Nasty solution, probably not secure at all, but works for me.. for now, as I didn't find anything better.